# Identifying neighboring edges of subsquares using Python

Tags: graph-theory, graph-connectivity

I have 12 edges, marked from 0 to 11. There are 4 squares marked in red from 0 to 3. How do I identify the neighboring edges of each square?

For example, square 0 has edges [0,2,3,5], square 1 has edges [1,3,4,6] and so on.

[image]

Comment: Well it alls depends on how you represent the data. Do you have specific information regarding each edge? Is the pattern in the picture continued for any amount of squares?

Comment: I have an adjacency matrix which tells me the connection between edges. I want to have a generic formula which works for large number of squares.